# C++ Eclipse g++: error: ./Matrix.o: No such file or directory make: *** [MatrixSample] Error 1

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program that can manipulate matrixes and I am getting that error in Eclipse on Ubuntu 14.04. I searched on google and on stack over flow, but I did not find anything that I could understand and I am stuck. May anybody help me out with this please?

The complete error message:

```
14:29:27 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project MatrixSample ****
make all 
Building file: ../Matrix.inl
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"Matrix.d" -MT"Matrix.d" -o "Matrix.o" "../Matrix.inl"
g++: warning: ../Matrix.inl: linker input file unused because linking not done
Finished building: ../Matrix.inl

Building target: MatrixSample
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++  -o "MatrixSample"  ./Main.o ./Matrix.o   
g++: error: ./Matrix.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [MatrixSample] Error 1
```

Here is the code:

```
/*
 * Main.cpp
 */

#include "Matrix.hpp"

int main()
{
    Matrix<int> firstMatrix();
    return 0;
}

/*
 * Matrix.hpp
 *
 */

#ifndef MATRIX_H_
#define MATRIX_H_

template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix();
private:
    int nbrRows;
    int nbrColumns;
};

#include "Matrix.inl"

#endif /* MATRIX_H_ */

/*
 * Matrix.inl
 */

template <typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix()
:nbrRows(0), nbrColumns(0){}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem was. I added .inl files as C++ Source file instead of adding it to C++ Header file. Now it's working fine.